# Upgrading existing dual boot computer from XP/Ubuntu to Win7/Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot

I have dual boot Ubuntu 9.10 & Windows XP.  Would like to do a full install of Windows 7 over the XP partition.

My assumption is that I can install windows 7, but it'll overwrite my boot files (from grub or whatever ubuntu uses).   How do i set it back up so I can dual boot again w/o having to re-install Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can restore GRUB using a Live CD, but if you want a simple way, [Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/) includes [Super Grub Disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/) that provides the option of doing it automatically for you.  There's a walkthrough [here](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/wiki/Howto_Fix_Grub).

Comment: thanks for the quick turnaround :)  at grandma's house fixing her computer

Answer (score 1):

Guide [restoring-overwritten-grub](http://fosswire.com/post/2009/5/restoring-overwritten-grub/) about using the Live CD.

Answer (score 0):

Just setup a dual boot from existing Vista to Win7/Ubuntu 9.10 with help of this article: http://lifehacker.com/5403100/dual+boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-in-perfect-harmony
This worked out very well. Pay special attention to assigning the mount point and the swap file definition.